# Interval of convergance $\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}$$

With what I now know the ratio test should give me

$$x * 1$$

So basically x. So that means my internal is (1,1) but this is wrong. Why?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the factorials in the denominator.

Comment: $e^x$ converges everywhere, and the extra factor of $n!$ on the denominator makes the convergence even faster.

Comment: How did you get $x*1$?  You should get $\frac{x}{(n+1)^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This time, the ratio limit is going to give you

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \left| \ x \ \cdot \frac{n! \cdot n!}{(n+1)! \cdot (n+1)!} \ \right| = \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \left| \ x \ \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1) \cdot (n+1)} \ \right| \ = \ 0 \ < 1 \ . $$

When you have a result which is *always* less than one, the radius of convergence is **infinite**.

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test:    $\ \ \ \left| \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right| = \left|  \dfrac{\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{((n+1)!)^2}}{\dfrac{x^n}{(n!)^2}}\right| =\left| \dfrac{x}{(n+1)^2} \right| $

for wich values of $x$ is the expression smaller  then $1$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: I don't understand this, at n = 0 the expression will be larger than 1 for most x values/

Comment: you should read carfully : "for wich values of $x$ is the expression smaller then $1$  as $n \to \infty$?".  You have to evaluate the limit as $n \to \infty$ that's why you can't use $n=0$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{|x|^n}{(n!)^2} \leq \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{|x|^n}{n!} < e^{|x|},
$$

so send $N \to \infty$ to see that that landlubbin' sequence converges absolutely for any $x$.

Comment: nice alternative answer. +1

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Why is it an absolute value?

Comment: I don't like this answer as much because it assumes the OP already knows $e^{x}$ converges everywhere.

Comment: @PaulthePirate, any sequence which converges absolutely will converge.  See, for example, [these notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AbsoluteConvergence.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For a series $\sum_n a_nx^n$ the radius of convergence is given by $$1/R=\limsup |a_n|^{1/n},$$
which in your case gives $1/R=0$ or $R=\infty$.

Comment: What does lim sup mean?

Comment: @PaulthePirate This [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) has some basic definitions and properties.